# How can I monitor DB calls in weblogic?

Tags: weblogic, health-monitoring

How do I find which DB call is currently executed by my weblogic server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use JDBCSpy provided by weblogic.

http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11035_01/wls100/jdbc_drivers/spy.html

You may need to switch the driver to one provided by weblogic.

[]s

Answer (score 1):

you can find it in .out log file